# Isomorphism between weighted Hilbert spaces

Tags: hilbert-spaces

It is a known fact that any two classical Hilbert spaces are isomorphic, in particular, any classical Hilbert space is isomorphic to $L^2$.

Consider now weighted Hilbert spaces, that is, Hilbert spaces with a weighted inner product

$ \langle f, g \rangle = \int f \ g \ w \ dx $

where $w(x)$ is the weight function. This situation appears frequently in Sturm-Liouville eigenvalue problems. Let's call $H_w$ to such weighted Hilbert space.

My question is: are all weighted Hilbert spaces also isomorphic?. In other words, is any weighted Hilbert space $H_w$ isomorphic to $L^2_w$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Consider $w(t) = 0$. The answer depends on the class where $w(t)$ lies.

Comment: So, the right question here would be "what are the conditions on $w(t)$ for $L_{2, \, w}$ and $L_{2}$ to be isomorphic?". This question could be generalized: "what are the conditions on measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ for $L_{2, \, \mu}$ and $L_{2, \, \nu}$ to be isomorphic?"

Comment: It is not exactly that all Hilbert spaces are isomorphic. It depends on the "dimension"

Comment: Hilbert spaces can have a variety of inner products and also not be composed of functions. How, fundamentally, is a weighted Hilbert space differ from the a Hilbert space as defined by the axioms?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. I am currently working on a Sturm-Liouville problem and my question refers to infinite dimensional functional spaces with an inner product defined by the integral shown in my question. Of course, the question could be extended to other cases, too.

Comment: By the way, I use the expression "classical Hilbert space" in the sense of Berberian, S.K. "Introduction to Hilbert Space" , 1961, Oxford University Press.

Comment: That does not help me understand what "classical Hilbert space" means because I don't have a copy of that book.

Comment: (Classical Hilbert space in the sense of Berberian means separable infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space which as is well-known is isomorphic to $\ell^2$ resp. $L^2$.)

Answer (score 0):

All Hilbert spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic, no matter how they're defined. Whatever "classical" means, that has nothing to do with it.